# Using keystore with javax.crypto for file encryption/decryption

Tags: java, cryptography, keystore

I was advised to look here: http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/DesFile.html for the source code of encryption/decryption using import javax.crypto. I have generated my key via keytool and now I don't know how to pass my generated keys into that application for encryption and decryption.

My situation is, that I have a XML file stored online (it stores configuration details) and before I parse it with a XML parser I have to decrypt it. First of all I should of course encrypt it, before it goes online.

**Question is: How to pass my generated keys into code visible in link in first row?**

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to load a KeyStore is documented in the [JavaDoc of the KeyStore class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
// get user password and file input stream
char[] password = getPassword();
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/mykeystore.jks")) {
    ks.load(fis, password);
}
```

Once you have loaded the key store you can load the key:

```
Key myKey = ks.getKey("mykeyalias", password);
```

The key alias is the one you have specified using keytool.
Using the `myKey` you can initialize the [Cipher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) instance or use for example a [CipherOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) / [CipherInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html)